# Running APK on Linux with Wi-Fi feature via adapter

Tags: linux, wifi, wifi-hotspot

I already know that Linux can run APK files, so it's possible to run Android apps on linux. But I've recently thought if would be possible to use wifi features from some apps.

**E.g:** GoPro Quik app can show a live preview of your camera. But you need to connect to camera's wifi hotspot in order to do that.

With that in mind, would it be theoretically possible to use a wireless adapter on my pc, then connect to the camera's wifi and then launching the app and see the live preview?

I would test it, but recently my adapter broke.

Comment: Linux in itself cannot "run" APK files. That requires pretty much the full Android execution environment. While that usually does have a Linux kernel underneath, doing things like you describe also requires Android to control most of the userland. So, you would need to run Android, not your typical desktop Linux. You can of course run Android in a virtual machine, but it will really depends on what control over your physical hardware you give that VM on whether it can connect to access points.

Comment: What are you using to run `apk` files? As Marcus said Linux by itself cannot run them. But maybe you are using **Waydroid** which can run some apps without any problem and the performance is great (but in my case the wifi connection doesn't work)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, that's a interesting approach. I was thinking about a virtualized environment running Android or Android-x86 (or any Android-based OS), and then giving the VM access to the adapter. But as mentioned earlier, I can't test because my adapter broke. So to try to find some answer, I researched for a few days on the subject and for some reason several people on the internet say that it is impossible to add hardware access to the adapter without the need of a custom kernel with the appropriate drivers installed. Since, Android may not have drivers added once it's installed.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I am currently using (but not limited to) Anbox.